# Оптимальный вариант ведения пользовательских логов

Tags: sql, mysql

Сейчас создана таблица `Log` в Mysql, которая заполняется событиями трегеров `(INSERT)` от других запросов в системе.
Таблица содержит информацию, которую нужно расширить, например, сейчас тригер (**INSERT AFTER**) имеет вид:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO log Set 
   LogTime = NEW.ArticleTime, 
   LogIdNote = NEW.idArticle, 
   LogName = NEW.ArticleName,
   LogType = 1,
   logTypeCategory = NEW.ArticleCategory,
   LogIdUser = NEW.ArticleToUserID;
END
```

Вся проблема в том, что для тригера нужно добавить еще пару полей, которых нет в `NEW` операторе. Например, имя пользователя:

```
LogIdUser = NEW.ArticleToUserID;
....
LogUserName = 'Username from current session PHP'
```

У кого есть какие предложения и идеи?

Comment: Разве селекты в триггерах запрещены?

Comment: Хм, не знал. Но чтобы сделать нужный select, необходимо знать значение переменных PHP, (id_user, type_user session).

Comment: LogIdUser = NEW.ArticleToUserID; - это разве не айдишник пользователя?

Comment: Оно, но type нет.

Comment: Опять возвращаемся: разве селекты в триггерах запрещены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e30f6/1)?

```
CREATE TRIGGER article_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON `articles` 
FOR EACH ROW 
  insert into log (LogTime, LogIdNote, LogName, LogType, LogIdUser) 
    select NEW.ArticleTime, NEW.idArticle, NEW.ArticleName, NEW.ArticleToUserID, u.type
    from users u where u.id = NEW.ArticleToUserID;
```

С session аналогично. Она же где-то в базе хранится? Если нет, то никак.

ЗЫ NEW - это не оператор, а кортеж, содержащий значения полей вставляемых записей. Т.е. запись, одна.

Comment: Да, примерно так, но дело в том, что в зависимости от type запрос делается либо в `users`, либо в `animals`.
____
Вопрос в принципе решен, просто нужно сделать вложенный запрос SELECT на выборку type по id.